# Correct way of doing free() in C

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have the following code that has an array of struct. Each array element has a copy of string. My question is what is correct way of doing free() after everything is done:

```
  1 #include <string.h>
  2 #include <stdio.h>
  3 #include <stdlib.h>
  4
  5 typedef struct testStruct {
  6         char *val;
  7         int index;
  8 } testStruct;
  9
 10
 11 int main()
 12 {
 13         char *value = "hello world";
 14         int NMAX = 10;
 15         testStruct *test_array = (testStruct *) malloc(NMAX * sizeof(testStruct));
 16
 17         int i;
 18         for (i = 0; i < NMAX; i++)
 19         {
 20                 test_array[i].val = strdup(value);
 21                 test_array[i].index = i;
 22
 23                 printf("added %d \n", i);
 24         }
 25
 26         for (i = 0; i < NMAX; i++)
 27         {
 28 //              free(test_array[i].val);  /* is it okay not to free the val field? */
 29         }
 30         free(test_array);         /* only do this free() on the entire array */
 31
 32 }
```

will the memory allocated to each "val" released at the end of the execution?

Comment: All memory is always released at the end of execution — except for a very few, very 'special' systems that are not in common use (you'll know if you're using one; in case of doubt, you aren't).  However, it is good practice to be able to release all memory before exit.  And for long-running processes, it is crucial that you don't leak memory.  Short-lived toy programs are one thing; you can get away with blue murder.  Long-lived major programs are another thing altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to free the `val` field, because [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strdup.html) generates a new copy of the string which is dynamically allocated.

To avoid many heap allocations, if you have an upper bound to the string length, then there is no need to use `strdup`. Just declare a static char array inside the struct itself:

```
const size_t MAX_LENGTH = 32;

typedef struct TestStruct
{
  char val[MAX_LENGTH];
  ..
}
```

and use `strncpy` to copy the content.

In addition there's no need to cast malloc returned pointer to the specified type, as in C a `void*` is convertible to other types without the need of an explicit downcast (this is not true in C++).

Answer (score 1):

Remember once you have free a pointer(address) you can't access memory via that address. strdup()  allocate memory(and also copy string) for each `test_array[i].val`, so first free it in a loop then free `test_array`:

```
for (i = 0; i < NMAX; i++)
{
     free(test_array[i].val); // free memory allocated by `strdup(value);`
}
free(test_array); // free by malloc() @ line number 15
```

It is something like reverse order of memory allocation steps.